# Make a 'sgame' table with a weird align next to it

Tags: floats, minipage

I am trying to do something as the next image

[image: this image]

The first matrix was did it with the ' sgame' package, but my problem is the right one. Note that 'Results' is not align with the two columns below, and the two columns are not longer than the box. I tryed to do it with a \begin{minipage} ... \end{minipage} but this only order the two things in the page. I can't do it, if someone could help me (or give me an advice) I would really appreciate it.

Comment: please show us the code you have now, as a small compilable example.  that way there will be something concrete to experiment with, and you'll get answers rather than guesses.

Comment: Sorry, I did not show my code because it was too bad. The image I did it with Photoshop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering\setlength{\BAextrarowheight}{2pt}
  $ \begin{blockarray}[t]{rccc >{\qquad}ll}
     & a & b & c & \BAmulticolumn{2}{>{\qquad}l}{\textbf{results}} \\
\begin{block}{r|c|c|c| >{\qquad}ll}
 \BAhhline{~|---~~~}
    a & 1,1 & 1,1 & 1,1 & s = 1 & j = 4 \\
 \BAhhline{~---~~~}
    b & 1,1 & 1,1 & 1,1 & p = 2 & k = 5 \\
 \BAhhline{~---~~~}
    c & 1,1 & 1,1 & 1,1 & c = 3 & \text{This is true.} \\
 \BAhhline{~---~~~}
\end{block}
  \end{blockarray} $
  \caption{A figure caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How can I remove the lines of the table for the last file? For example, if I want to make a 2x2 matrix at the left and 3 lines at the right?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I end the block before and works!

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to use two adjacent `tabular`s. Depending on the content on the right, you can align it at the `[t]`op (or elsewhere):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mc}{\multicolumn{1}{c}}% Just for short-hand

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ *{4}{ c | } }
    \mc{} & \mc{$a$} & \mc{$b$} & \mc{$c$} \\
    \cline{2-4}
    $a$   &   $1,1$  &   $1,1$  &   $1,1$ \\
    \cline{2-4}
    $b$   &   $1,1$  &   $1,1$  &   $1,1$ \\
    \cline{2-4}
    $c$   &   $1,1$  &   $1,1$  &   $1,1$ \\
    \cline{2-4}
  \end{tabular}\quad
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ l l }
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Results:} \\
    $s = 1$ & $j = 4$ \\
    $p = 2$ & $k = 5$ \\
    $c = 3$ & This is true.
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A figure caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```